# InvalidOperationException was unhandled by user code, WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox, dispatcher, ivalueconverter

I have some WPF GUI (hosted in WinForm) which has multiple `CheckBoxes`. The default value of `IsChecked` of each `CheckBox` need come from different boolean fields in some background data. Each boolean field in the background data is mapped to a `CheckBox` in the `VisualTree`. So I bind the `IsChecked` property of each `CheckBox` to the `CheckBox` itself and use a Converter to fetch the corresponding boolean value in the background data. This way the `CheckBox` becomes an input to the Converter function so that the Converter can know its location in the `VisualTree` and query the correct boolean field in the background data. When the user changes the `CheckBox`, `Checked/Unchecked` event-handlers will set the value back to the boolean field in the background data. The XAML is like this:

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ModuleWithEnableControl">
        <WrapPanel>
            <CheckBox Content="Enable" 
                      IsChecked="{Binding Path=., RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, Mode=OneTime, 
                                  Converter={StaticResource moduleEnableDisableConverter}
                                  }"
                      Checked="ModuleEnabled" Unchecked="ModuleDisabled"
                />
        </WrapPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
```

The Converter code is like this:

```
class ModuleEnableDisableConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
      System.Windows.Controls.CheckBox theBox = (System.Windows.Controls.CheckBox)value;
      //Here suppose to get the default value of the CheckBox
      //but just return true for now
      return true;
    }
}
```

The Checked handler code is like this:

```
    private void ModuleEnabled(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBoxResult result = MessageBox.Show("Enabled", "Confirmation", MessageBoxButton.YesNo, MessageBoxImage.Question);
        if (result == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
        {
          //Check the sender (CheckBox)'s location in the VisualTree,
          //Do set the boolean field in the background data
        }
        return;
    }
```

When program starts, the Converter runs first, since it returns ture, then immediately the Checked handler `ModuleEnabled` runs. Then the problem happens when executing the `MessageBox.Show()` in the handler, a `Popup` window complains:

> InvalidOperationException was unhandled by user code

and

> Dispatcher processing has been suspended

but message are still being processed.

If I comment out the `MessageBox.Show()` line, the program executes as expected. If I don't bind the `IsChecked` to the `CheckBox` itself, no problem either, the `MessageBox` shows perfectly when user changes the `CheckBox`. I'm wondering why the `MessageBox.Show()` in the event-handler has conflict with the binding Converter? Also, is there a way to not trigger the Checked handler when setting the initial value using the binding?